How do I calculate the volume of this solid of revolution (involving new coordinates)?
I wanted to calculate the volume of $y = x²$ rotated about $y = x$ in a simple, easy to remember way, because the "official" method (https://www.emathhelp.net/notes/calculus-2/applications-of-integrals/volume-of-solid-of-revolution-about-slant-line/) is kind of difficult and
unintuitive for me. I saw in a forum (https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/solids-of-revolution-around-y-x.669647/) that a change of coordinates can be made in order to make the calculation simpler.
So I did that change ($p = x + y$ and $q = x - y$) and the equation $y = x$ became $q = 0$. The problem was the equation $y = x²$, because it gives to me $(p - q)/2 = ((p + q)/2)²$, which seems pretty difficult to solve for p or q. However, the graph seems reasonable to me and I wonder if there is some way to do the calculation using that new function. Thank you very much for reading and answering if possible!
Graph
